# How to display invalid value text to the user in Combo Box in WinForm C#

Tags: c#, list, winforms, combobox, invalidation

I have a Combobox in WinForms with a set of values in it. Now I'll check if the value selected in the combo box is valid or not. Once done, if the value is invalid, I need to show the value in red colour. How to do it?
For example: Consider a ComboBox with elements **{apple, mango, orange}**. Now a new element is added to the list, say, **Carrot**. Given that, the **carrot** is an invalid value, I want to show the value carrot in Red Color in the UI.
Please let me know how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `DrawMode` property of your combo box to `OwnerDrawFixed`

```
this.comboBox1.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
```

Define method for custom drawing of combo box items

```
private void ComboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var text = comboBox1.Items[e.Index] as string;
    e.DrawBackground();
    if (text == "orange")
    {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics,
            text, e.Font, e.Bounds.Location, Color.Red);
    }
    else
    {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics,
            text, e.Font, e.Bounds.Location, e.ForeColor);
    }
}
```

Subscribe this method to event `DrawItem` of your combo box

```
this.comboBox1.DrawItem += 
    new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.ComboBox1_DrawItem);
```